# Using boost::push_relabel algorithm on customised graph-type

Tags: c++, boost-graph

My graph has the following declaration

```
struct vertex_info 
{
  std::string name;
  std::string label;    
  unsigned int type;
  bool isND; 
};

struct edge_info 
{
  std::string name;
  long capacity;
  long residualCapacity;
  long rev;
};

typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::bidirectionalS
  , vertex_info, edge_info > expr_graph_t;
```

I have constructed a graph (flow network) `flowG` with `source` and `sink` nodes. Now I want to calculate max-flow using `push_relabel` method given in boost graph library. I am calling the function as following .

```
  push_relabel_max_flow(flowG, source, sink
      , get(&edge_info::capacity, flowG)
      , get(&edge_info::residualCapacity, flowG)
      , get(&edge_info::rev, flowG)
      , get(boost::vertex_index, flowG)
      );
```

Compiler (g++) is generating long error messages ([pasted here](http://pastebin.com/Zn9zn3px)). I suspect that I am not able to pass correct types of maps to the function. Function signature is available [here in boost-doc](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/graph/doc/push_relabel_max_flow.html).

There are many examples given in document but they are using a graph is different than mine. I can not change the graph declaration else a lot of code will break. I am not used to boost `property_map` concept.

Comment: One problem (maybe THE problem) is that `reverse_edge_map` requires a property map with key_type=edge_descriptor and value_type=edge_descriptor and the one you use has value_type=long. You can use `adjacency_list_traits<vecS,vecS,bidirectionalS>::edge_descriptor` to declare your `rev`. If you add a simple example graph, I can try to make it work.

Comment: Thanks man. Something is happening. If I can't sort it out, I'll create a small example and let you know.

Comment: @llonesmiz Man, you saved my day. Can't thank enough. Please add this as answer and I'll accept it. Thanks again. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution is due to llonesmiz.

The problem is that `reverse_edge_map` requires a property map with key_type=`edge_descriptor` and value_type=`edge_descriptor` and the one I used has value_type=`long`. I declared `rev` as `adjacency_list_traits<vecS,vecS,bidirectionalS>::edge_descriptor`. And it compiled thought I generated a seg-fault which I believe is a problem with logic of function and not with the prototype of the function.

Comment: [Here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4c3IQV$0) is an example using [this example graph](http://www.boost.org/libs/graph/doc/graph_theory_review.html#sec:network-flow-algorithms).